Tensorflow saving model works but loading it doesn't
I trained an LSTM model in tensorflow, and it works fine, but when I save the model and then try to load it from disk, it throws me a ValueError when loading. FYI saving and loading works for other models, here is the code to create the model:
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(int_vectorize_layer)
model1.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim))
model1.add(SpatialDropout1D(drop_lstm))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(units=32)))
model1.add(Dropout(drop_lstm))
model1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model1.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])```

Here is the model's summary:
model summary
saving and loading the model:
#works fine
model1.save("model.keras")
#this line throws the error
loaded_model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.keras")

the Error:
ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>:

Layer 'lstm_cell' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['kernel', 'recurrent_kernel', 'bias']

List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>]

Full Error with stack trace:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[141], line 1
----> 1 loaded_model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.keras")

File ~/Desktop/projects/SPARK-STREAMING-PFA/Model/my-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:176, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    173         is_keras_zip = True
    175 if is_keras_zip:
--> 176     return saving_lib.load_model(
    177         filepath,
    178         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    179         compile=compile,
    180         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    181     )
    182 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
    183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)

File ~/Desktop/projects/SPARK-STREAMING-PFA/Model/my-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:152, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    147     raise ValueError(
    148         "Invalid filename: expected a `.keras` extension. "
    149         f"Received: filepath={filepath}"
    150     )
    151 with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
--> 152     return _load_model_from_fileobj(
    153         f, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode
    154     )

File ~/Desktop/projects/SPARK-STREAMING-PFA/Model/my-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:207, in _load_model_from_fileobj(fileobj, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    204         asset_store.close()
    206     if failed_trackables:
--> 207         _raise_loading_failure(error_msgs)
    208 return model

File ~/Desktop/projects/SPARK-STREAMING-PFA/Model/my-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:295, in _raise_loading_failure(error_msgs, warn_only)
    293     warnings.warn(msg)
    294 else:
--> 295     raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>:

Layer 'lstm_cell' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['kernel', 'recurrent_kernel', 'bias']

List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>]

I'm running the code on python-3.10.12 here are all the library versions:
absl-py==2.1.0
asttokens==2.4.1
astunparse==1.6.3
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
comm==0.2.2
contourpy==1.2.1
cycler==0.12.1
debugpy==1.8.1
decorator==5.1.1
exceptiongroup==1.2.1
executing==2.0.1
flatbuffers==24.3.25
fonttools==4.51.0
gast==0.5.4
gensim==4.3.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.62.2
h5py==3.11.0
idna==3.7
ipykernel==6.29.4
ipython==8.23.0
jedi==0.19.1
joblib==1.4.0
jupyter_client==8.6.1
jupyter_core==5.7.2
keras==3.2.1
kiwisolver==1.4.5
libclang==18.1.1
Markdown==3.6
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.8.4
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mdurl==0.1.2
ml-dtypes==0.3.2
namex==0.0.8
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.26.4
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optree==0.11.0
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.2
parso==0.8.4
pexpect==4.9.0
pillow==10.3.0
platformdirs==4.2.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.43
protobuf==4.25.3
psutil==5.9.8
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
Pygments==2.17.2
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
pyzmq==26.0.2
regex==2024.4.16
requests==2.31.0
rich==13.7.1
scikit-learn==1.4.2
scipy==1.13.0
seaborn==0.13.2
six==1.16.0
smart-open==7.0.4
stack-data==0.6.3
tensorboard==2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.36.0
termcolor==2.4.0
threadpoolctl==3.4.0
tornado==6.4
tqdm==4.66.2
traitlets==5.14.3
tweet-preprocessor==0.6.0
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1
wcwidth==0.2.13
Werkzeug==3.0.2
wordcloud==1.9.3
wrapt==1.16.0

I've tried saving the model other ways, I've tried saving it in h5 format, but it gives me a deprecated warning and an error, I've tried saving the weights and reloading them to a model with the same architecture, but then the textVectorization layer needs to be adapted to the training data or loaded from another file, which is not an ideal situation, the optimal solution as I see it to make this code work so i can easily load the model from a single file. I think the bidirectionnal layer is at the root of the problem, since that's where the only two LSTM layers in the neural network exist. If you have any ideas on how to solve the problem I'd be willing to try it out. Any and all help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

I fixed the problem, turns out I was right, the problem is in the bidirectionnal layer, what fixed my problem for me was removing it, here is the new model with the same achieved accuracy, structure:
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.string)
x = int_vectorize_layer(input_layer)
x = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(x)
x = SpatialDropout1D(drop_lstm)(x)

#Changed Bidirectionnal to this
forward_lstm = LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False, name='forward_lstm')(x)
backward_lstm = LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False, go_backwards=True, name='backward_lstm')(x)
concat_lstm = Concatenate()([forward_lstm, backward_lstm])

x = Dropout(drop_lstm)(concat_lstm)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model1 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

now I can save and load the model without a problem.
